# How to prevent intermediate images from being created but keep the sizes available for selection in the media library?

Tags: plugins, uploads, media

I am writing a plugin that will make use of an image service for resizing images. I want to keep the ability for users to select different image sizes, but I don't want Wordpress to create intermediate images sizes when uploading an image. The only image that should be saved in the uploads directory is the image that was uploaded.

How can I prevent Wordpress from creating the intermediate image sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `intermediate_image_sizes` filter and return an empty array:

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', '__return_empty_array' );
```

`__return_empty_array` is a helper function in WordPress, the above is all you need!

Comment: I tried this and it does successfully stop the other sizes being created, however the size drop down in the media library now only shows the full size, I require the sizes in that drop down to remain unchanged. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: Try this filter instead: `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced`

Comment: Tried `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced`, same problem as before, the sizes in the drop down disappear. Where does Wordpress do the actual resizing and file creation?